# Is there anything I am doing incorrectly while memoizing my results in a Unique Path algorithm?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

I have this code that is giving me a correct result for (1,2) or (2,1). However, for the (2,2) grid it is giving me 3. This is what the code is printing while running it. From where it is calculating an additional 1?

```py
class Solution(object):
    def uniquePaths(self, m, n, memo= {}):
        """
        :type m: int
        :type n: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        if (m,n) in memo or (n,m) in memo:
            print("calling for", (m,n), memo)
            return memo.get((m,n), memo.get(n,m))

        if m == 1 and n == 1:
            return 1
        
        if m == 0 or n == 0:
            return 0

        memo[(m,n)] = self.uniquePaths(m-1, n, memo) + self.uniquePaths(m, n-1, memo)
        print(memo)
        return memo[(m,n)]
```

## printed output

> {(1, 2): 1}
> ('calling for', (2, 1), {(1, 2): 1})
> {(1, 2): 1, (2, 2): 3}
> 3

Comment: You have not added what the question is that you are trying to solve. Neither you have explained how your code works. Please refer [minimal reproducible exmaple](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question appropriately or else you might attract downvotes.

Comment: Also, add the initial parameters with which you call the function

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will make the changes to understand the question better.